# OpenLdap TLS authentication setup

Tags: openldap, ubuntu-12.04, tls

I am trying to setup openldap on ubuntu 12.04 by following this guide
https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/openldap-server.html

When I tried to enable TLS on the server by creating a self signed crtificate as decribed in the guide above, I got the following error

command that I ran

```
ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/ssl/certinfo.ldif
```

Content of ldif file

```
dn: cn=config
add: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
-
add: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/ldap01_slapd_cert.pem
-
add: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/private/ldap01_slapd_key.pem
```

**Error Message**

```
ldap_modify: Inappropriate matching (18)
        additional info: modify/add: olcTLSCertificateFile: no equality matching rule
```

After hours of searching on google, I have not found anything that tells much about this error.
Does anyone have any more information on this?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but once you have it fixed, you may want to [force the use of SSL](http://serverfault.com/questions/459718/configure-openldap-with-tls-required).

Answer (score 9):

These are `SINGLE-VALUE`. Use `replace` instead of `add`.

Also note, changes in the attributes may require a restart of `slapd`. (Not everything is a run-time configurable as we'd like.)

Your schema is probably:

```
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.12.2.3.0.70 NAME 'olcTLSCertificateFile' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.12.2.3.0.71 NAME 'olcTLSCertificateKeyFile' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
```

A little explaination: `ldapmodify` `add` causes `slapd` to make sure you aren't putting in the attribute valie pair twice by doing an equality match. From what I can tell it should be using `2.5.13.6 NAME 'caseExactOrderingMatch'`, but I've not sure I've ever tried an `add` for these attributes. This behavior might be completely normal.