# OpenLDAP configure LDAPS, restart fails

Tags: ssl, ldap, ssl-certificate, openldap

I am attempting to get ldaps working with openldap.  I have a wildcard ssl certificate that was issued for this domain and have used ldapmodify to add the relevant files to cn=config as show [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/455529/openldap-tls-authentication-setup).

Once I have completed this, I am unable to restart OpenLDAP.

I have completed setup for OpenLDAP and have confirmed that I can bind successfully using ldap.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 TLS on an AWS EC2 instance with ports 389 AND 636 open.

Some diagnostics:

**/etc/init.d/slapd restart**

```
restart
 * Stopping OpenLDAP slapd                     [ OK ] 
 * Starting OpenLDAP slapd                     [fail]
```

**slapd -u ldap -g ldap -d 65**

```
563e5b20 @(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd  (Ubuntu) (Sep 15 2015 18:19:13) $
    buildd@lgw01-53:/build/openldap-2QUgtL/openldap-2.4.31/debian/build/servers/slapd
ldap_pvt_gethostbyname_a: host=ip-172-31-62-171, r=0
563e5b20 daemon_init: listen on ldap:///
563e5b20 daemon_init: 1 listeners to open...
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap:///)
563e5b20 daemon: listener initialized ldap:///
563e5b20 daemon_init: 2 listeners opened
563e5b20 No passwd entry for user ldap
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was that openldap was being denied access to the key file by apparmor.  Issue was resolved by proper configuration of openldap's permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else comes here looking for a solution, **using certificates from LetsEncrypt**, this should fix it.

Set the correct access permissions for the LetsEncrypt directories and files in two steps.

**setfacl**

```
$ sudo setfacl -m user:openldap:r-x /etc/letsencrypt/live
$ sudo setfacl -m user:openldap:r-x /etc/letsencrypt/archive
```

**apparmor**

Create /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.slapd with the following content.

```
/etc/letsencrypt/live/your.domain.here r,
/etc/letsencrypt/archive/your.domain.here r,
/etc/letsencrypt/archive/your.domain.here/** r,
```

Restart apparmor.

```
sudo service apparmor restart
```

Slapd should now restart fine and be accessible via LDAPS/TLS.